# composer require conflict with symfony/yaml

Tags: laravel, composer-php, swagger

hi iam trying to install swagger by typing:

```
composer require "darkaonline/l5-swagger"
```

but i am getting an error due to a conflict with `symfony/yaml`

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/yaml ^5.4, found symfony/yaml[v5.4.0, v5.4.2, v5.4.3] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 2
    - codedungeon/phpunit-result-printer is locked to version 0.19.14 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - codedungeon/phpunit-result-printer 0.19.14 requires symfony/yaml ^2.7|^3.0|^4.0 -> found symfony/yaml[v2.7.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.37] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^5.4).

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require symfony/yaml:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require symfony/yaml:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

and in the `composer.lock` i found:

```
"conflict": {
    ...
    "symfony/yaml": "<4.4"
},
```

Comment: The version you are using of  `codedungeon/phpunit-result-printer` is not compatible with Symfony YAML v5. Either update or remove that dependency.

Comment: Keep in mind that `codedungeon/phpunit-result-printer` in v0.19.14 is pretty old (released  in Sep 2018) - why not update that?

Comment: thanks, it was sloved by updating it, then  i updated all dependencies